# Swift - type constraints for subclasses with common superclass

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, protocols, type-constraints

General description:

I need to be able to use in a configurator class instances of 2 subclasses of UIViewController and UITableViewController made by me, but I need it to be checked that it's one of these 2 subclasses and not just a general class, so in the method definitions I am expecting a type of this 2 (both of them conform to a common protocol).

In depth:

I have a protocol

```
protocol UIViewControllerNavigationBarConfig
{
    var doneButtonTitle : String? { get set }

    func configureNavigationBar()

    func disableNavigationBarConfig()
}
```

And I have a subclass of UIViewController (ViewControllerWithNavigationBarConfig) which adopts this protocol and also a subclass of UITableViewController(TableControllerWithNavBarConfig) which also adopts this protocol.

Now, I have a configurator class which knows how to customize my controllers with aproximate definition like here (I jus did not include the other functions and func body):

```
class ControllerConfigurator<NavigationBarConfigurable : UIViewController where NavigationBarConfigurable : UIViewControllerNavigationBarConfig>
{
    class func configureNavigationBarWithInfo(controller: NavigationBarConfigurable)
}
```

The problem is... if I define the type constraint NavigationBarConfigurable as above in the class definition (ControllerConfigurator) I am not able to use "configureNavigationBarWithInfo" for any of my subclasses because everytime I try do it for example here:

```
class SelectQuestionsController: TableControllerWithNavBarConfig
{
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        ControllerConfigurator.configureNavigationBarWithInfo(self)
    }
}
```

I receive "type UIViewController does not conform to protocol", which is of course logical, but my thought was "my both subclasses have UIViewController as a superclass, so if I put the condition to be a UIViewController and to conform to that protocol, it should suit my bot subclasses".

How can I define the type constraint in order for it to work?

Comment: I believe, you will have to type the call to `ControllerConfigurator`, e.g. `ControllerConfigurator<SelectQuestionsController>. configureNavigationBarWithInfo(self)`

Comment: following your suggestion I modified he method
     class func configureNavigationBarWithInfo<NavigationBarConfigurable>(controller: NavigationBarConfigurable) after which I start receiving a lot of other errors like "NavigationBarConfigurable does not have a member named "doneButtonTitle" even though in the protocol this property is specified

Comment: I did not said to modify the declaration of the method. I said to modify the way you are calling the method.